# VSTS performs web deploy successful, but website does not work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to get Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) to perform a web deploy of my app. According to the VSTS UI the web deploy is successful, but when I browse the deployed web site it shows the default IIS screen ("Welcome - IIS").

This is my publish step in the build pipeline:

[image: Publish build artifacts step]

This is my release definition:

[image: Relase task]

This is the resulting deploy folder:

[image: Resulting deploy folder]

[image: Web app deploy step]

Build.log (with replaced values) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y6q2Cjr1gxBVMcHeh6n_r7qu-JpJFSyC/view

Do I need to add an additional step to the release pipeline to get the .zip files extracted?

Comment: You need to de-layer your problem here.  Pinpoint the issue in IIS first, then figure out what (if anything) you are doing wrong in VSTS.

Comment: I can't give you a definite answer without seeing how you have the `IIS Web App Deploy` configured, but I'm willing to bet the issue is in that task. Based on your output, it looks like you pointed the task to a directory and not the zip file.

Comment: Can you show the detail release logs by adding variable `system.debug` value as  `true`?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added the IIS web app deploy config as well as the detail release logs.. However, I did replace some user + company specific values in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add an additional step to extract your zip, but you need to tell the `IIS Web App Deploy` task to deploy your zip file and not a folder. You have specified a folder for the `Package or Folder` input, so the task is doing exactly as you told it to do, deploy the specified folder.

If you only have one zip file in your build artifacts, the default value for this field, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip`, will pickup your zip file and correctly deploy it. If you have multiple zip files in your build artifacts, you will need to specify the full path to the zip file in order for it to deploy.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer as it is a part of the actual solution. The artifacts deployed (all the .zip files), each represent a project in my .sln file.

This answer has lead me in the direction, to get my website working.